# How to get date from js in correct format? Month and days get reversed

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am calling an ajax for getting some values for editing data.
As a part of my object, I am sending the date field.
My problem is that when I receive the date value in the controller, date format is wrong - my dates and months are reversed. And because of that I can't compare them where I need to.
But my months and days are reversed. For an example , instead of 3rd October, it returnes 10th of March.
How to fix this?
I am sending the date field from js in a object like this:

```
ExamsDataU = {
            classId: classIdValue,
            date: dateValue
        };
```

And in my controller I tried:

```
DateTime dateToCheck = Convert.ToDateTime(dto.Date);
```

Comment: Hint: Use `toISOString()` against JS date and convert it using `DateTime.ParseExact`.

Comment: can you write a brief utils function to swap them?

Comment: You need to send the the date in the same format as the culture in your server (or using an overload of `.ToDateTime()` that accepts an [IFormatProvider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.iformatprovider?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Comment: As @TetsuyaYamamoto points out, you could use `DateTime.ParseExact` which allows you to pass a `format` argument, specifying how you'd like to parse.

Comment: This is a client side issue, not server side. Thus, send the date to the server in the format that the server needs. You can do so using JavaScript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first thing you should know is date parsing with `Convert.ToDateTime()` depends to the current culture used in server (you may check it using `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture` property). You can try one of these methods to parse JS date format properly inside controller action method:

**1) Using `DateTime.ParseExact()`/`DateTime.TryParseExact()` with custom format**

On this way it is necessary to specify date format before parsing date:

```
// specify custom format
string dateFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy";
DateTime dateToCheck = DateTime.ParseExact(dto.Date, dateFormat, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

**2) Using `DateTime.ParseExact()`/`DateTime.TryParseExact()` with ISO 8601 format**

Use `date: dateValue.toISOString();` to convert JS date into ISO 8601 format and then convert it:

```
// specify ISO format
string dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffZ";
DateTime dateToCheck = DateTime.ParseExact(dto.Date, dateFormat, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.RoundtripKind);
```

This way is better than the former because no need to write additional date representation code in client-side, also you can adjust date representation to local time if necessary.

**Notes:**

a) For specified culture, you can try `CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo()`:

```
var culture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Name);
DateTime dateToCheck = DateTime.ParseExact(dto.Date, dateFormat, culture);
```

b) You can use `if` condition to check if the date string is valid when using `DateTime.TryParseExact()`:

```
DateTime dateToCheck;
if (DateTime.TryParseExact(dto.Date, dateFormat, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out dateToCheck))
{
    // do something
}
```

Comment: I used your #2 solution. The problem I experienced was the I had to remove the leading zeros on the dateFormat = "yyyy-M-dTH:m:s.fffZ". toISOString returned the following  string in this format "2019-11-2T20:0:0.000Z" Removing the leading Zeros worked great for me.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
var date = new Date('2014-01-06');
var newDate = date.toString('dd-MM-yy');
```

or

```js
var dateAr = '2014-01-06'.split('-');
    var newDate = dateAr[1] + '-' + dateAr[2] + '-' + dateAr[0].slice(-2);

console.log(newDate);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you for this! I ended up using another solution, but this javascript code is great!

Comment: No problem bro hehe ^_^